# 2010 Census Tiger County shp file with defined coastal land area

Tags: census, tiger, shapefile, county

I am looking for a 2010 Census Tiger Shape file that hugs the coastline and doesn't include the ocean in county boundaries.  I have a pre 2010 file that did this and I can't seem to find a 2010 version that follows the same pattern.
For Reference, I have been looking here: http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/

Below are visuals of the difference

**Pre 2010 - Hugs land**
[image: Pre 2010 - Hugs land]

**2010 Includes Ocean**
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**
The new files are now available and known as "Cartographic Boundary Files".  More detail on the other types here http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html   The County file discussed above is available here: http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html

---

**The official file is not currently available as of 5-12-2011, but should be sometime this summer.**

My team might create our own version for use in the interim. If we do, I will post back a download link here.

We put in an official query to the geo.geography at census.gov team and got an (impressively) fast answer.  Below is their response.

> We do not currently have shapefiles
>   that hug the coastline for 2010.  We
>   are in the process of creating our
>   cartographic boundary files, which are
>   more generalized and are clipped to
>   the shoreline, but they are not ready
>   yet.  We hope to release these
>   shapefiles this summer.
>
> In the mean time, you could use the
>   hydrography shapefiles to clip county
>   boundaries to the shoreline.  The
>   shapefiles are available for download
>   here: 
>   http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html.
>   You could download the line
>   hydrography file and use the lines
>   that have an MTFCC code of P0002 for
>   perennial shoreline.  You would have
>   to do this by county though, so it may
>   be intensive work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just overlay the areawater layer from the 2010 TIGER files if all you need is a quick way to mask out the water areas. The areawater layer is pretty big and cumbersone, though.