# Census Shapefiles Fit to Land

Tags: qgis, shapefile, census, tiger, county

I'm looking for an oceans or coastlines shapefile that's a more detailed than what Natural Earth has to offer (1:10m).

I'm working with 2000 Census county shapefiles, but it doesn't cut out lakes or oceans. So the county boundaries are a bit blobby. If I clip it to Natural Earth's oceans, a sliver of New York County gets left inside King's County. (I'm a perfectionist using QGIS and Tilemill).

[image: County shapefiles example]

Comment: So you only need the oceans surrounding the United States, right?

Comment: On closer inspection, I'm looking for lakes and oceans. Something to get the counties to hug the land. Currently reading over this last thread.

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9578/2010-census-tiger-county-shp-file-with-defined-coastal-land-area

Answer (score 3):

Found the [cartographic files here](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html)

[image]