# does the census bureau provide clipped / water-bounded files as nice as certain cities?

Tags: shapefile, r, hydrography, county, government

[this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9578/2010-census-tiger-county-shp-file-with-defined-coastal-land-area) says they do but when i compare what i can find in the [cartographic boundary files](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_description.html) section of the census bureau's gis page, they don't look as good as certain shapefiles provided by the city government.  am i missing something?  or do i have to scrounge through each city's website to get this level of detail (assuming it's there at all)

comparison photos of new york city and reproducible R code below.

[image]

[image]

```
library(maptools)

tf <- tempfile() ; td <- tempdir()

# from http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_cousub.html

download.file( "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2013/cb_2013_36_cousub_500k.zip" , tf )
z <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )
ny.shp <- readShapePoly( z[ grep( 'shp$' , z ) ] )
nyc.shp <- subset( ny.shp , as.numeric( as.character( COUNTYFP ) ) %in% c( 5 , 47 , 61 , 81 , 85 ) )
# shows some water.
plot( nyc.shp )


# from http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/districts_download_metadata.shtml

download.file( "http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/nybb_14c.zip" , tf )
z <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )
nyc.shp <- readShapePoly( z[ grep( 'shp$' , z ) ] )
# very awesome.  does not show water.
plot( nyc.shp )
```

Comment: You could download the census data, and then clip it by a highly detailed USA polygon, that should yield suitable results

Comment: @Maksim but where is the highly detailed usa polygon?  i had thought my census.gov link above was a highly detailed polygon, but comparing the two images.. it's not.

Comment: Not too sure about that, I have StreetMap Premium, I'm sure a Google search will help

Comment: Natural Earth might be one source, or OpenStreetMap

Comment: @neuhausr i think the answer to my question might be "no."  :(  natural earth provides [lots of layers](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/) but [the census bureau provides the same](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2013/main).  i was hoping for an integrated file that just showed every place in the nation, finely blanking out the water